# Correct way to use personal access token credential to clone git repo

Tags: jenkins

I have an azure devops git repository that I want to use for a Jenkins job.

I have created a personal access token for the azure devops project that allows me to clone the repository.

If I create a username/password credential (with the personal access token as the username and the password left blank), I can use that credential to clone the repository.

The problem is that when I do this, the full text of the personal access token is displayed in the configuration, which seems pretty insecure to me:
[image]

I tried adding the personal access token as a "secret text" credential, but that credential did not show up in the combo box of credentials I could use for the git repository.

What is the best way of using a personal access token in a git credential?

Comment: If you use `http(s)` protocol for Repository URL,  try add your credential as `username and password` Credential

Comment: I don't understand -- I already *am* using a username/password credential.  But when I do so, the personal access token is visible.

Answer (score 2):

I put the personal access token as the password in a username/password credential and it worked.  It didn't matter what I put in for the username.